# How will I know if my thread is already done doing tasks? (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

With the code below, how will I know if my thread is already done doing tasks? My purpose is to kill that thread in order to free memory. Or how should I do it?

```
private delegate void DelegateSetProperties(DataTable dataSource, string valueMember, string displayMember);

    Thread thread1;
    DelegateSetProperties delegateSetProperties;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        delegateSetProperties = new DelegateSetProperties(SetProperties);

        thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitValues));
        thread1.IsBackground = true;
        thread1.Start();
        // should I abort thread1 here? if I abort it, does it frees the memory occupied by thread1?
    }

    private void SetProperties(DataTable dataSource, string valueMember, string displayMember)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = valueMember;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }      

    void InitValues()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable
                {
                    TableName = "CATEGORY",
                    Columns = {
                                {"CategoryCode", typeof(string)},
                                {"Name", typeof(string)},
                              }
                };

                dt.Rows.Add("C1", "Category1");
                dt.Rows.Add("C2", "Category2");
                dt.Rows.Add("C3", "Category3");
                // and so on...
        comboBox1.Invoke(delegateSetProperties, new object[] { dt, "CategoryCode", "Name" 

});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never abort a thread unless your process is terminally sick and is going to die anyway. Very bad things happen (for example, irretrievable locks). The code is fine *as is*. When the `InitValues` method ends, so will the thread.

If the `InitValues` method is brief, perhaps consider `ThreadPool`, but otherwise; leave it.

You *might* want to consider adding some exception handling, so that if `InitValues` throws it doesn't kill the entire `AppDomain`, and you should understand that *most* of the time here is going to be spent updating the UI on the UI thread (unless your table is being populated from an external source, and the procedural `Rows.Add` is just illustrative).

Answer (score 0):

One option is Thread.Join. This will make the main thread wait for the child thread to complete execution before continuing.

Another option is look into the System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker. It is a managed threading class provided by MS. It will notify you when it is complete.